# Database model / design best practice

Tags: database-design, relations, dimensional-modeling

I'm looking for a some guidance/advice on how to best model my data.

Some background: I have location information that I'm trying to model. There are two categories of locations (company and non-company locations), as such, not all locations have the same data elements.

The two tables below represent my current model (without enumerating all columns).

My thoughts on the current design:

1. If I combine the two tables below I will have to put in null values for `company_code`, because not all locations have a `company_code`. I do not want to add nulls values because of the huge number of different data elements between the two different types of locations.
2. The `location_company` and `location` are two important concepts in the company. I would like to have tables in the database two represent these two concepts.

[image]

**I'm unclear if this is the best approach. Any thoughts on the design would be greatly appreciated. Any additional thoughts are also welcomed.**

If my issue is unclear, please ask. I will graciously add clarification. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that if the company locations and non-company locations store a fair amount of different data, then to avoid a bunch of NULLS I would have two tables, and let the application insert data into the appropriate table. A different approach could be to have a table [Locations], with all the data that it needs, then have a table [CompanyLocations] and another table [Non-CompanyLocations]. The tables for company and non-company locations would then reference a base table using a foreign key, something very like what you have in the image, if I am reading it the same way you are.

Comment: This confirms my initial thoughts on how to approach this.Thank you for your thoughtful answer.